# Sort a DataTable by a custom format DateTime column

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a data table with 2 columns: the first column is the name of the city and the second column is a date, and I have to sort it ascending by date.

The date's format was `MM/dd/yyyy` and I successfully sorted the table using
`DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Date asc";`

But I had to change the format to `dd/MM/yyyy` and it stopped working.

What do I have to do in order to sort the table using this custom format?

This is the input 

`Ploiesti    19/05/2017
Ploiesti    20/05/2017
Ploiesti    21/05/2017
Sinaia  21/05/2017
Sinaia  22/05/2017
Sinaia  23/05/2017
Constanta   12/06/2017
Constanta   13/06/2017
Constanta   14/06/2017
Constanta   15/06/2017
Predeal 20/06/2017
Barsana 11/06/2017
Barsana 11/07/2017
Borsa   22/05/2017
Borsa   22/06/2017
Borsa   22/07/2017
Brasov  30/05/2017
Brasov  30/06/2017`

And this is the output after I use DataTable.DefaultView.Sort:

`Barsana 11/06/2017
Barsana 11/07/2017
Constanta   12/06/2017
Constanta   13/06/2017
Constanta   14/06/2017
Constanta   15/06/2017
Ploiesti    19/05/2017
Ploiesti    20/05/2017
Predeal 20/06/2017
Ploiesti    21/05/2017
Sinaia  21/05/2017
Sinaia  22/05/2017
Borsa   22/05/2017
Borsa   22/06/2017
Borsa   22/07/2017
Sinaia  23/05/2017
Brasov  30/05/2017
Brasov  30/06/2017`

Comment: Mind sharing code example and the error that you're currently experiencing?

Comment: Hi, I am not getting any error. Using that sort property it sorts the table by the day of the date, despite of what year it is.

Comment: With the information given, how do you think we can help???

Comment: I uploaded the input/output

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i implemented date formatting.

```
$('#CategoryTable').DataTable({
                    serverSide: true,
                    processing: true,
                    paging: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'Category/GetData',
                        type: "POST",
                    },
                    order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
                    orderId:"CategoryId",
                    columns: [
                        { data: "CategoryId", visible: false },
                        { data: "CategoryName", title: "Category Name" },
                        { data: "CategoryDescription", title: "Category Description" },
                        { data: "CreatedDate", title: "Created Date", render: function (data) {
                               return data.format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            data: "CategoryId", title: "Action", render: function (data) {
                                return '<a class="btn btn-sm u-btn-secondary" href="/Category/Edit/'+data+'">Edit</a>'
                            },
                            orderable:false
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to sort the datatable by using new format.

Code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                dr["Date"] = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
            }
            table.DefaultView.Sort = "Date asc";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Date");
            table.Rows.Add("Ploiesti", "19/05/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Ploiesti", "20/05/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Ploiesti", "21/05/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Sinaia", "22/05/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Sinaia", "19/05/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Constanta", "23/05/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Constanta", "12/06/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Barsana", "13/06/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Brasov", "11/07/2017");
            table.Rows.Add("Brasov", "22/07/2017");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
```

Result:

[image]